# ¿Cómo puedo ingresar de nuevo a mi VPC de Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Una consulta, tengo un becario que se conectó a la instancia de manera gráfica y el cual ingresó una IP fija, con lo que el sistema se durmió y ya no permite al acceso a la misma, alguien que sepa cómo solucionar el tema, ya que no tengo mucha experiencia en VPC y pues no respaldé la instancia desde una semana, con lo que necesito toda esa información...

Alguien me puede ayudar con el tema?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que le cambió IP a la máquina, quitando la que tenía? Si es así, es de sospechar que la máquina sigue corriendo, pero está con esa otra IP. ¿La sabes? ¿Has hablado con el soporte? Es probable que ellos puedan revertir el cambio, pero nunca he visto un caso similar. Dudo que alguien más pueda conectarse vía escritorio remoto al equipo, sino alguien que esté dentro de la misma red física y pueda ponerse dentro de la misma sub-red. Ellos en cambio, es probable que puedan conectarse a través de alguna consola del virtualizador.

Comment: Exacto! le pedí que hiciera la IP fija desde el admin de cloud para dar salida a una web, pero lo hizo desde remoto, lo que hizo que se durmiera el entorno, la IP que estableció si la tengo, pero no me permite entrar tampoco, con lo que se me agotan las opciones...

Comment: ¿Qué dice el soporte?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes acceso al  panel de Google Cloud?

- Sí es así simplemente ve a Compute Engine > instancias, y conectate a tu instancia vía SSH, en el caso de que tu instancia sea Windows de igual forma puedes acceder por RDP o resetear el usuario de RDP si es necesario.
- Al seleccionar la instancia, puedes ver las interfaces de red...
- Otra opción sería crear un Snapshot, de la instancia y crear una nueva a partir de ese, así no perderías nada.